# Как сделать выборку уникальных пользователей по месяцам в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы, для клиентов чей прием еще не случился, и для тех, кто уже сходил на прием.
Цель: достать статистические данные о количестве новых посетителей за каждый месяц, начиная с самого первого клиента.
Вот что имею на данный момент:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), month
FROM ((SELECT name, `surename`, `inst`, MONTHNAME(date) as 'month'
       FROM clients
LEFT JOIN clients_trash ON name = name_trash AND surename = surename_trash AND inst = inst_trash
       GROUP BY inst, name, month(date))
      UNION
      (SELECT name_trash, `surename_trash`, `inst_trash`, MONTHNAME(date_trash) as 'month'
       FROM clients_trash
       GROUP BY inst_trash, name_trash, month(date_trash))) as q
GROUP BY month;
```

Структура БД:

```
create table if not exists clients
(
    ID_client int auto_increment
        primary key,
    service varchar(32) not null,
    master varchar(32) not null,
    date date not null,
    time time not null,
    name varchar(32) not null,
    surename varchar(32) not null,
    inst varchar(32) not null,
    unique (service, master, date, time)
);
```

И аналогичная таблица, только с припиской "_trash".

Как я понимаю, логика выполнения запроса должна быть примерно следующая: Мы берем клиентов за второй месяц(так как в первом итак все уникальные), и сравниваем с первым месяцем посредством "NOT IN", после третий месяц со вторым и первым и т.д. Только вот SQL я знаю так себе, и как реализовать это - пока идей нет.

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. Что такое "новые", как они соотносятся с таблицей "_trash"? Пока видеться просто группировка в основной таблице по месяцу.

Comment: не совсем понимаю, чем отличаются данные в таблице ```_trash```, но все делается довольно банально - в подзапросе для каждого клиента находите минимальную дату посещения, а затем в основном запросе группируете по месяцу и находите количество клиентов. пример кода тут https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db9b3fbcca1c3cb9fce62bb03748a0f5

Comment: @AlexR. Постараюсь объяснить. Новые - означает, что если клиент впервые записался на Май, то относительно "Мая" он является новым. Также если он в будущем запишется на "Июнь", условно, то он уже не будет считаться новым, так как впервые он записался на "Май". 
Две таблицы практически ничем не отличаются, их можно восприниматься, как одну, только в "_trash", уже состоявшиеся приему, то есть те, где дата и время ниже текущего. ( Можно было бы просто добавить в таблицу clients дополнительное поле, со статусом, знаю. Но я был молод и глуп )

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, мне нравится ваш ход мысли, действительно должно сработать, спасибо! Правда будет трудность в объединении данного запроса на две таблицы, но это мне кажется я решу.
Таблицы, как я уже написал выше, практически ничем не отличаются, только в "_tarsh" значения "date" ниже текущей даты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные находятся в 2х таблицах - объедините их, затем найдите минимальную дату для каждого клиента, а затем посчитайте количество посетителей по месяцам:

```
select year (min_date), month (min_date), count(full_name)
from (select full_name, min(date) as min_date
from ( select surename+' '+name as full_name, date from clients
union 
select surename+' '+name, date from clients_trash) xx
group by full_name ) x
group by year (min_date), month (min_date)
```

Так же, не вижу у вас в таблицах ID клиента или условия уникальности на Имя+Фамилия, соответственно, данные могут быть не совсем корректными.